# Proper way to assign and work with WPF DataContext in Resources

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

My application needs to open a `UserControl` that needs to have a `parameter/property` to contain a year.
For this year i will have my control show some edit values.

I'm running into the problem that my `Window.Resource` section i have declared has a `contextmenu` that i'm attching to a `Gridview`.  From this `contextmenu` in the resource i cannot bind directly to my `Commands` on my `ViewModel`.

I solved this problem by adding my `ViewModel` as a `StaticResource` in my `Xaml`.  Unfortunatly this cause my xaml to generate my ViewModel and it's impossible for me to pass my parameter or property 'year' and when i'm retrieving my data it is done for the year=0.

Is there a way to replace the viewmodel binding i have provided for my contextmenu so it can access the viewmodel i have set in code?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModel x:Key="viewModel" />

    <ribbon:ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu"
                         x:Shared="False"
                         Placement="MousePoint" >
        <ribbon:Menu Focusable="false">
            <ribbon:Button 
                Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModel}, Path=MyCommand}"
                Label="MyLabel"/>
        </ribbon:Menu>
    </ribbon:ContextMenu>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes this it possible. You could create a dummy-class which holds the DataContext:

```
public class Proxy:DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(Proxy));
    public object Data 
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

refer to it in the resources and bind the DataContext to its Data-property:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:Proxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Now the Data Property holds your ViewModel and you can bind to it like so:

```
<ribbon:ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu"
                     x:Shared="False"
                     Placement="MousePoint" >
    <ribbon:Menu Focusable="false">
        <ribbon:Button 
            Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource proxy}, Path=Data.MyCommand}"
            Label="MyLabel"/>
    </ribbon:Menu>
</ribbon:ContextMenu>
```

Comment: I can use this one :) I'll try to implement this adding a Static Current Propoerty to my ViewModel and assigning the correct one to it :)